# Best practices for integrating QTP with Maven build Scripts?

Tags: maven-2, qtp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I invoke QTP test suits automatically from Maven/Hudson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164443/can-i-invoke-qtp-test-suits-automatically-from-maven-hudson)

i want to Integrate QTP with the MAVEN build scripts. So that i can achieve continuous integration. Whats the best practices for achieving this? Will Hudson be of any use here?

Comment: Have a look at [Invoke QTP Test Suits automatically from Hudson?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164443/invoke-qtp-test-suits-automatically-from-hudson) (it also covers running QTP from Maven).